# Regular expression for alphanumeric characters

Tags: php, regex

need regular expression which could match a string like that `"1B7FL26X3WS731388"`. Alphanumeric 17 character lenght.

I am using this expression.

```
$rEX    =  '/([A-Z0-9]){17}/';
```

but it also return a portion from a string like this `"FGD798791B7FL26X3WS731388POPOD"`;

I need to select a string which is exactly 17 character long 18th character should not be Alphanumeric.

Comment: That's how regular expressions work. If you need it to only match if the 18'th character is non-alphanumeric, you should specify that in your expression.

Comment: Thank you every one for your response I got what I needed
$rEX    = '/([A-Z0-9]){17}([^A-Za-z0-9]){1}/';

it is now working for me

Answer (score 2):

Add begin and end to your pattern:

```
$rEX = '/^([A-Z0-9]){17}$/D';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use ^ $ delimiters

$rEX    =  '/^([A-Z0-9]){17}$/';

To only allow uppercase alphanumeric 17 length string

You regular expression will allow all strings that contains a SUBSTRING of uppercased alphanumeric 17 lenght string.

Answer (score 0):

`$rEX = '/[^A-Z0-9]([A-Z0-9]){17}[^A-Z0-9]/';` should do. `[^...]` negates the character class.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rEX = '/[^A-Z0-9]+([A-Z0-9]){17}[^A-Z0-9]+/';
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]){17}([^a-zA-Z0-9])*$
```

Comment: this will match "1234567890abcdefghijk###" and will return "567890abcdefghijk" in group 1

Answer (score -1):

try this....

```
<?php
$title='1B7FL26X3WS731388';
$result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $title);
echo strlen($result);
?>
```